# How to determine if a folder is in network path?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to write to a folder in network drive, I need to find out if the path is really a netowk drive or local one. Is there any api which can help me to determine that? Please help. I tried with DirectoryExists but it returns true for both network drive and local one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`PathIsNetworkPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, can you explain your comment and downvote? this function works fine when you pass a path  like  `Z:\Foo`  where Z: is a mapped drive letter.

Comment: That API, according to docs, treats all unc paths as being network paths. But local drives have network names too.